# Anythingslider with custom FX stops and restarts animating randomly in Firefox

Tags: anythingslider

I am writing code for a wordpress theme and I use anything slider with custom FX. It works perfectly in all browsers except Firefox. It starts working as expected but after some cycles it starts to display the slides with fadein - fadeout and time zero. After some cycles it returns to its normal behavior. This fade/display - normal/display transition, appears only in Firefox. Any suggestion?

The theme, still under development, can be found [here](http://king-themes.com/talos/#&panel1-1&panel2-1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the [latest version](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider) (currently v1.8.7). I think it was an issue with the z-index of the panels which has been updated in all themes.